# Java : ProgressBar does not display when click on the button

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jprogressbar

In the application that I am developing these days required to show a progress bar when click on the 'convert' button and the following is my code,

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

private JPanel panel2 = null;
private JPanel panel2 = null;

JProgressBar progressBar = null;
JButton button = null;

Main f1 = null;
Main f = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

try
{
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel());

}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void convert(){

            f = new Main();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(700, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setTitle("Fromat Conversion");

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.setForeground(Color.white);

            button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Convert");

    panel1.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            f.setContentPane(panel1);
    f.setVisible(true);

            f1 =  new Main();
            f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(457, 100);
        f1.setTitle("Conversion Progress");
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.setForeground(Color.white);

            progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(35);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        panel2.add(label3, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel2.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            f1.setContentPane(panel2);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                f1.setVisible(true);
  }
  });

  }

  }
```

but when I click on the button Progress bar frame does not display.

Anybody have idea why is that ?

thank you

Comment: See also [How to Use Progress Bars](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java GUI JProgressBar not painting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154847/java-gui-jprogressbar-not-painting)

Comment: Would be a good start to provide code that can actually be compiled...

Answer (score 1):

your code does not compile.

this actually does compile and displays your progress bar.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Pipo extends JFrame{

private static JPanel panel1 = null;
private static JPanel panel2 = null;

static JProgressBar progressBar = null;
static JButton button = null;

static Pipo f1 = null;
static Pipo f = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    f = new Pipo();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(700, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setTitle("Fromat Conversion");

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.setForeground(Color.white);

    button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Convert");

    panel1.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    f.setContentPane(panel1);
    f.setVisible(true);

    f1 =  new Pipo();

    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setSize(457, 100);
    f1.setTitle("Conversion Progress");
    f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.setForeground(Color.white);

    progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setValue(35);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

    panel2.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    f1.setContentPane(panel2);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            f1.setVisible(true);
        }
  });

  }
}
```