# JDialog with a JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jprogressbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java GUI JProgressBar not painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154847/java-gui-jprogressbar-not-painting)

I have a GUI that has the GUI Locked while processing an Action Event, so I need a progress bar to show up.  I can get the `JDialog` to show up but the progress bar won't show up.  I used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and `invokeAndWait()` but to no avail.  The progress bar will not show up.  Any hints or help would be appreciated.

```
pb = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
pb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 40));
pb.setString("Working");
pb.setStringPainted(true);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Progress: ");
JPanel center_panel = new JPanel();
center_panel.add(label);
center_panel.add(pb);
dialog = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Working ...");
dialog.getContentPane().add(center_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this); // center on screen
dialog.toFront(); // raise above other java windows
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        pb.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
});
Thread.sleep(5000);
template = AcronymWizardController
    .sharedInstance().readAndDislpayDocx(contdFile);
parseDocxText(contdFile);
pb.setIndeterminate(false);
savedFile.setText(contdFile.toString());
dialog.dispose();
```

Comment: @JBNizet It's a duplicate to about half the Swing questions that get asked here ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yes indeed. And that makes it even worse to ask it once again, hence my close vote. I wonder how it's possible not to find the answer. The duplicate question I linked to is the first question in the "Related" section on the right.

Comment: @JBNizet Hay, you got +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 4):

Swing is a single threaded API, that is, all the UI updates and modifications are performed from within a single thread (known as the Event Dispatching Thread or EDT).  Anything that blocks this thread will stop it from processing additional updates, like repaints.

You have a number of choices.  Your immediate requirement is to move the long running task off the EDT.  To do this you can either use a `SwingWorker` or a `Thread`.

From your description, a `SwingWorker` will be easier.

For a simple example, check out [JProgressBar won't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094666/jprogressbar-wont-update/13095992#13095992)

For more information, you should check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

You other choice would be to use something like a `ProgressMonitor`, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394898/how-create-progress-bar-while-file-transfering/13395076#13395076)

Comment: +1 nice answer and knowledge on EDT

Comment: Thanks for the info but the netbeans platform has a progress util that I was able to use that didn't require thread management.