# How to make a jprogressbar to run in parallel with my algorithm

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java GUI JProgressBar not painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154847/java-gui-jprogressbar-not-painting)
>   [Can a progress bar be used in a class outside main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main)

I am using Netbeans drag and drop to do an application. I will get input from user and use the input to run my algorithm. The algorithm will take different time to run and then show its result in a new frame. While waiting the algorithm to run, I wish to add in a progress bar.
I add in the below code when the user click the button submit input.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

    final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0,250000);
    bar.setValue(1000);
    bar.setIndeterminate(false);
    JOptionPane jO = new JOptionPane(bar);

    Thread th = new Thread(){

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 1000 ; i < 250000 ; i+=10000){
           bar.setValue(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
};
th.start();

final JDialog dialog = jO.createDialog(jO,"Experiment X");
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);

//Algorithm goes here
```

The progressbar do show up and run.But when the progress bar value is update until the end, only my algorithm run. I see through others example, but I not really understand how it works.

Can someone tell me where I got wrong?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. Use a background thread such as can be provided by a SwingWorker. Please read the progressbar and swingworker tutorials for more on this which Google will help you find.

Comment: Here are the tutorial links: [progressbar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), [concurrency in swing (and SwingWorker tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: *"..then show its result in a new frame."*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for assessment (bad) and alternatives (many).

Answer (score 4):

Some of the most important concepts in Swing are

**DO NOT** perform any long running/blocking operations within the Event Dispatching Thread (ETD).  This will cause the UI to appear "frozen" and non-responsive. What's nice is, you seem to understand this.

**DO NOT** create or modify ANY ui component from any thread OTHER then the EDT. You're not doing this.

You best cause of action is to take advantage of the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), this allows you to perform long running operations, while providing progress feedback to listeners.

```
public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ProgressPane progressPane = new ProgressPane();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(progressPane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

//                progressPane.doWork();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ProgressPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar progressBar;
        private JButton startButton;

        public ProgressPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            progressBar = new JProgressBar();

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(progressBar, gbc);
            startButton = new JButton("Start");
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(startButton, gbc);

            startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    startButton.setEnabled(false);
                    doWork();
                }
            });

        }

        public void doWork() {

            Worker worker = new Worker();
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });

            worker.execute();

        }

        public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                startButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

                for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                    int progress = Math.round(((float) index / 1000f) * 100f);
                    setProgress(progress);

                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You're other choice would be to use a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) or, if you're really desperate, use [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), but, I'd really encourage you to use `SwingWorker` instead ;)